# WordPress how to exclude certain categories via functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, wordpress-theming, categories

I'm trying to exclude certain categories and all user archives
e.g.

- https://example.com/category/slug
- https://example.com/author/name

From my WordPress-Site via `functions.php`, rerouting them to home.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
/* Route categories to home */
function reroute_wp_categories(){
  if( is_category( array('category1', 'category2', 'category3' )) || is_author() ) {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->is_home(); //set to Home
  }
}
```

with category x being the category slug.

This doesn't work at all and I'm running out of ideas.

Grateful for any help/ideas.

Comment: For the category part of the question, have you already thried these approachs? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/160705/best-way-to-redirect-category-to-page-and-hide-category

Comment: Those are only good for single categories or all categories. I need to have an array of specific categories based on what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. In your functions.php add the following

```
function reroute_wp_categories( $query ) {
    if ( is_author() || is_category(array('category1', 'category2', 'category3' )) ) {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'reroute_wp_categories' );
```